# Not getting the text box value for tabpanel?

Tags: android, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In my application, i have a tab panel in the bottom of the screen. The three tabs are Home, Add Wishlog and Add Feedback. Now when i am clicking the home tab, it is showing me some icons. In Add Wishlog and Add Feedback tab, i added some text boxes and some buttons. I added the addwishlog tabs like below in the screen

```
{
        xtype : 'addwishlog',
        styleHtmlContent : true,
        title : '+ Wishlog',
        iconCls : 'favorites',
    },
```

Here is the addwishlog.js file:::

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.AddtoWishlog', {
                    extend : 'Ext.Container',
                    xtype : 'addwishlog',
                    config : {
                        ui : 'light',
                        scrollable: {
                            direction: 'vertical',
                            directionLock: true
                        },
                        items : [
                                {
                                    xtype : 'container',
                                    id : 'LoginScreen',
                                    docked : 'top',
                                    items : [
                                            {
                                                xtype : 'image',
                                                docked : 'left',
                                                height : 92,
                                                id : 'Logoimage',
                                                ui : '',
                                                width : 120,
                                                src : 'app/images/small_logo.png'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                xtype : 'titlebar',
                                                cls : 'mytitlebar',
                                                docked : 'top',
                                                height : 80,
                                                ui : 'blue',
                                                items : [ {
                                                    xtype : 'label',
                                                    height : 36,
                                                    html : 'Add to Wishlog',
                                                    id : 'title',
                                                    margin : 20,
                                                    style : 'font: normal Bold 20px droid sans; color:#AB3951',
                                                } ]
                                            } ]
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype : 'panel',                                    
                                    autoHeight: true,
                                    items: [{
                                        xtype : 'container',
                                        id : 'dashboardiconcontainer',
                                        height: 400,
                                        layout: 'vbox',
                                        items : [
                                                {
                                                    xtype : 'container',
                                                    id : 'topitembox',
                                                    layout : {
                                                        type : 'hbox'
                                                    },
                                                    margin : '10 0 0 10',
                                                    height : 50,
                                                    items : [ {
                                                        xtype : 'textfield',
                                                        id : 'itemname',
                                                        labelWidth : '40%',
                                                        label : 'Name of the item',
                                                        width : 320
                                                    }, {
                                                        xtype : 'textfield',
                                                        id : 'barcodetextfield',
                                                        width : 300,
//                                                        value: 'test', 
                                                        margin : '0 0 0 10',
                                                        labelWidth : '40%',
                                                        label : 'Enter Barcode'
                                                    }, {
                                                        xtype : 'button',
                                                        height : 40,
                                                        scope: this,
                                                        margin : '0 0 0 10',
                                                        id : 'scanbutton',
                                                        ui : 'orange',
                                                        width : '80',
                                                        text : 'scan barcode'
                                                    } ]
                                                },

                                                {
                                                    xtype : 'container',
                                                    height : 160,
                                                    id : 'cameraimagecontainer',
                                                    margin : '10 0 0 10',
                                                    layout : {
                                                        type : 'hbox'
                                                    },
                                                    items : [
                                                            {

                                                                html : '<img style="width:180px; height:150px;display:none;" id="capturedimage" src="" />'
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                xtype : 'container',
                                                                id : 'btncontainer',
                                                                width : 120,
                                                                margin : '0 0 0 10',
                                                                layout : {
                                                                    type : 'vbox'
                                                                },
                                                                items : [
                                                                        {
                                                                            xtype : 'button',
                                                                            height : 73,
                                                                            cls : 'capturebtn',
                                                                            id : 'capturebtn',
                                                                            width : 100
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            xtype : 'button',
                                                                            height : 73,
                                                                            margin : '10 0 0 0',
                                                                            cls : 'choosephotobtn',
                                                                            id : 'selectphoto',
                                                                            width : 100
                                                                        } ]
                                                            },

                                                            {
                                                                xtype : 'container',
                                                                id : 'additionalinfo',
                                                                margin : '10 0 0 10',
                                                                width : 400,
                                                                layout : {
                                                                    type : 'vbox'
                                                                },
                                                                items : [
                                                                        {
                                                                            xtype : 'textareafield',
                                                                            height : 80,
                                                                            width : 380,
                                                                            id : 'additionalinfo',
                                                                            label : 'Add Additiona Details',
                                                                            labelWidth : '40%',
                                                                            placeHolder : ''
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            xtype : 'selectfield',
                                                                            margin : '5 0 0 0',
                                                                            width : 300,
                                                                            label : 'Select Category',
                                                                            options : [
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        text : 'Food',
                                                                                        value : 'first'
                                                                                    },
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        text : 'Sports',
                                                                                        value : 'second'
                                                                                    },
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        text : 'Electronics',
                                                                                        value : 'third'
                                                                                    } ],
                                                                            labelWidth : '40%'
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            xtype : 'textareafield',
                                                                            id : 'Addmoretag',
                                                                            margin : '10 0 0 0',
                                                                            width : 320,
                                                                            placeHolder : 'Add any other tags you want '
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                             xtype : 'button',
                                                                             height : 54,
                                                                             id : 'Addwishlog',
                                                                             margin : '10 0 0 0',
                                                                             ui : 'orange',
                                                                             width : 250,
                                                                             text : 'Add to my wishlog'
                                                                             }

                                                                        ]
                                                            } ]
                                                } ]
                                    }]
                                } ]
                    }
                });
```

The same way i am doing for addFeedback also.  Now while i am trying to fetch the value of any of the text field from the addWislog screen, I am getting the error. Some time it is telling the getValue() method is not for this object..while trying to do using

```
this.getIDofTextbox().getValue();
```

although i took the correct reference in the controller. If i am trying using getCmp(), i am getting null value.

I am literally confused, because for other screen, i am getting the value from text boxes. The problem i am getting only in this tabpanel js files.

Here is my app.js file:

```
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true
});

Ext.application({
    views : ['dashboardpanel', 'TitlePanel', 'wishlogsummary', 'ConsumerSignup', 'FeedbackSummary', 'ConsumerSignin', 'AddFeedback'],
    models : [ 'MyModel', 'wishlistmodel', 'feedbacksummarymodel' , 'loginmodel'],
    stores : [ 'name', 'wishlistsummarystore', 'feedbacksummarystore' ],
    name : 'MyApp',
    controllers : [ 'MyController' ],
    requires:['Ext.ux.touch.Rating'],

    fullscreen: true,


    launch : function() {

        var Login = {
                xtype: 'login'
        }
        var Dashboard = {
                xtype: 'dashboard'
        }

        var Wishlogsummary = {
                xtype: 'wishlogsummarylist'
        }

        var AddtoWishlog = {
                xtype: 'addwishlog'
        }
        var Consumersignup = {
                xtype: 'consumersignup'
        }
        var FeedbackSummaryList = {
                xtype: 'feedbacksummarylist'
        }
        var Consumersignin = {
                xtype: 'Consumersignin'
        }

        Ext.Viewport.add([Login,Dashboard,Wishlogsummary, FeedbackSummaryList,Consumersignup,Consumersignin]);
    }

});
```

Did i have to change something in the application architecture??

Please help as i am stuck in this issue for a long while and not able to find out the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is some problem in my architecture. Now i able to fixed it.